# Finding the Power of a Complex Number using DeMoivre's Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex number given is $(1+i)^5$ .

I used DeMoivre's Theorem which $Z^n$ = r[(cos $n$$\theta$ + $i$sin $n$$\theta$)]. When solved I got $Z^n$= cos5 + isin5 . However, the answer key says the answer is -4-4$i$ . I have no idea where they got the four from . Am I missing a step ?

Comment: If $z=r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ then $z^n=r^n(\cos nt+i\sin nt)$.

Comment: For real  $A,B,$ not both $0,$ we have $A+iB=R(\cos t+i\sin t)$ where $R=\sqrt {A^2+B^2}\;=|A+iB|$, and $ \cos t=A/R$ and $\sin t=B/R$.... So $(A+iB)^n=R^n (\cos nt+i\sin nt)$ for $ n\in \Bbb N.$

Comment: @KellyNgo Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$(1+i)=\sqrt 2(\cos \pi/4+i\sin \pi /4)$$

then

$$(1+i)^5=(\sqrt 2)^5(\cos 5\pi/4+i\sin 5\pi /4)$$

then convert it again.

Comment: Where is the radical two from ?

Comment: Note that $$|1+i|=\sqrt{1^2 +1^2}=\sqrt 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\require{cancel}\,(1+i)^2=\bcancel{1}+2i+\bcancel{i^2}=2i$, then $(1+i)^5=(1+i)\cdot(1+i)^4=(1+i)\cdot(2i)^2=\ldots$